# "Missing ) after..." on a line, Javascript

Tags: javascript, new-operator

So I am creating a "Silly Story Generator" in Javascript and after fixing a few errors that popped up I encountered "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

After reading more about it I learned that it occurs when there is an error with how a function is called. This might be a typo, a missing operator, or an unescaped string.

I checked my code and I cannot seem to find the mistake, string on line 38 looks okay.
Thank you.

```js
randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {
    if (customName.value !== '') {
        let name = customName.value;

    }
    if (document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
        let weight = Math.round(300);
        let temperature = Math.round(94);
    }
    story.text = ""
    story.style.visbility = 'visible';


    var newStory = storyText;

    let xItem = randomValueFromArray;
    let yItem = randomValueFromArray;
    let zItem = randomValueFromArray;

    function newStory(buttonPress) {
        newStory.contentString.replace("insertX", "insertY", "insertZ")
        content.contentString.replace("xItem ", "yItem", "zItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Indenting your code properly would help you find errors more easily

Comment: swap the `;` and the `)` at the end of the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code is Badly formatted.

At `newStory.contentString.replace("insertX", "insertY", "insertZ";)`
You had a semi-colon inside the the parenthesis.
You are also missing two curly braces near the end.

I suggest getting a good IDE or using the formatting features that come with the one you use.

```js
randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {
    if (customName.value !== '') {
        let name = customName.value;

    }
    if (document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
        let weight = Math.round(300);
        let temperature = Math.round(94);
    }
    story.text = ""
    story.style.visbility = 'visible';


    var newStory = storyText;

    let xItem = randomValueFromArray;
    let yItem = randomValueFromArray;
    let zItem = randomValueFromArray;

    function newStory(buttonPress) {
        newStory.contentString.replace("insertX", "insertY", "insertZ")
        content.contentString.replace("xItem ", "yItem", "zItem");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have written a semicolon before the closing parentheses

```
newStory.contentString.replace("insertX", "insertY", "insertZ");
```